# How to use phpmyadmin pma_table_info

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dbase

phpmyadmin(9) is the advanced features dbase. I finally got the pma_history table in that dbase to work by adding 3 lines in \xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php :
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['QueryHistoryDB']      = TRUE; 
    $cfg['QueryHistoryMax']     = 25;

pma_table_info ?? What is that for? It has remained at (0) rows and I am intrigued. It may well be of some very good purpose. Anyone have a thought on what it does, when, how?

Comment: Used just a single word `pma_table_info` in google and found several publicly available PMAs. No way! :-S

Comment: Unreal  @zerkms, I got similar results. I thought for a second to alter the pma table at publicUnprotectedSite.com . Na, don't try that!

Comment: @zerkms,, ran out of edit time above. Adding.. I got the table_info table to function. In pma, any table, Structure tab, clk "Relation view" at table bottom, "Choose field to display" dropdown, clk a column name. Only for user reference it seems.